# In jqgrid input textbox i am not able to enter the values in firefox

Tags: firefox, input, jqgrid, textbox

Hi in the jqgrid i have created a row , which manually takes the input so on click of the text box it is not focusing and no blinking of cursor , not able to enter the values in it. Only when i use the tab and navigate to that text box then only it is taking the input. please help me , here is my code :

```
$("#variablesGrid").jqGrid({
    datatype: 'local',
    data: variableForGrid,
    colNames: ['Data Type', 'Is Array', 'Field Name', 'Action'],
    colModel: [
        {name: 'dataType', index: 'dataType', width: 50, editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: {value: dataTypeChoices}, align: "left"},
        {name: 'isArray', index: 'isArray', width: 17, editable: true, formatter: "checkbox", edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: {value: "true:false"}, align: "center"},
        {name: 'fieldName', index: 'fieldName', width: 40, editable: true, align: "left", editrules: {custom: true, custom_func: check}},
        {name: 'act', index: 'act', width: 10, sortable: false}
    ],
    rowNum: 100000,
    //rowList: [5, 10, 20],
    pager: '#variablesPager',
    gridview: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    sortname: 'invdate',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: 'desc',
    caption: 'Variables',
    editurl: 'clientArray',
    width: 900,
    height: 250,
    loadonce: true,
   autoencode: true,


    loadComplete: function () {
        var table = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            updatePagerIcons(table);
            enableTooltips(table);
        }, 0);
    },
    gridComplete: function () {
        var ids = jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid('getDataIDs');
        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            var cl = ids[i];
            ce = "<div title=\"\" style=\"float:left;margin-left:5px;\" class=\"ui-pg-div ui-inline-del\" id=\"jDeleteButton_12\" onclick=\"deleteGridRow('" + cl + "','" + hasError + "');\" onmouseover=\"jQuery(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');\" onmouseout=\"jQuery(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');\" data-original-title=\"Delete selected row\"><span class=\"ui-icon ui-fa fa-trash\"></span></div>";
            jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], {act: ce});
        }
    },
    onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
        if (isNewRow === false) {
            if (rowid !== lastSel) {
                var fieldNameValue = jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid('getCell', lastSel, 'fieldName');
                if (fieldNameValue != false) {
                    if (fieldNameValue.indexOf("name=\"fieldName\"") > 0) {
                        fieldNameValue = $("#" + lastSel + "_fieldName").val();
                        if (fieldNameValue == "" || fieldNameValue == " " || MDBPMUtils.hasSpaces(fieldNameValue)) {
                            hasError = true;
                            grid.jqGrid('saveRow', lastSel);
                            $("#" + lastSel + "_fieldName").focus();
                            jQuery('#variablesGrid').jqGrid('setSelection', lastSel);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (hasError === false) {

            if (rowid !== lastSel) {
                if (lastSel) {
                    grid.jqGrid('saveRow', lastSel);
                }
                lastSel = rowid;
            }
            grid.jqGrid('editRow', rowid, true);
            return true;

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: If you use `datatype: 'local'` then you could easy create the demo in JSFiddle which reproduces the problem. Currently it's unknown which version of jqGrid and from which fork of jqGrid you use ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). The code have many undefined variables (`grid`, `lastSel`, `hasError`, `isNewRow`, `dataTypeChoices`, `grid_selector`, `variableForGrid` and so on). It would be important to have an example of test data `variableForGrid` which you use as the input.